# Drawing graph of correlation coefficients in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graph, graphics, matlab-figure, pearson-correlation

In Matlab, I have an `n^2 x n^2` matrix `Corr_M` containing the Pearson correlation coefficients between all entries of a set of `n x n` matrix `M`, such that `Corr_M(i,j)` is the correlation coefficient between `M(i)` and `M(j)` for some `M` in the set. Note that `Corr_M` is symmetric.

I would like to graph `Corr_M` by showing links between different entries of `M`, where the link between `M(i)` and `M(j)` is colored, say, red if `Corr_M(i,j)` is positive and blue if it is negative. The thickness of the link indicates how strong the correlation is (preferably where links being 0.1 apart, perhaps even smaller, are distinguishable).

For a `3 x 3` `M` this could look like the following:

[image]

Not all entries will be connected, as many of them are not correlated (so a correlation coefficient of zero will not result in a link being shown). Note that self-correlations are not shown. Instances such as the one seen in the bottom row, where a naive implementation might simply place one line on top of the other, are problematic, but such a naive implementation is very welcome still.

**Is there a standard way of doing this, perhaps with some of the in-built graph-theoretic functions of Matlab (which I, unfortunately, do not know the scope of)?**

**If there isn't, then how can I implement this?**

Comment: `Corr_M = corr(M)` finds pair-wise correlations between columns of `M`. So `Corr_M(1, 2)` is the correlation between the 1st and the 2nd columns of `M`. Based on this, I am not sure what the visualisation represents. For example, which correlation coefficient does the thick blue line in your plot between (2, 1) and (1, 2) points represent?

Comment: @VaheTshitoyan Yes, it was ambiguous, see my edit: `M` represents a *set* of matrices. I take all the ij-th entries and collects them in a vector, and similarly with some other entry, and then I find the correlation coefficients between these two vectors. The result is an entry in `Corr_M`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `graph` object in Matlab. The following example assumes that your  `Corr_M` is a `n`x`n` matrix (see below):

```
% set the source of the lines:
s = repelem(1:n-1,n-1:-1:1);
% set the target of the lines:
t = nonzeros(triu(repmat(2:n,n-1,1)).').';
Corr_M(~Corr_M) = nan; % replace zero weights with nan
weights = nonzeros(tril(Corr_M,-1));
% create the graph object:
G = graph(s,t,weights,n);
% mark the lines to remove from the graph:
threshold = 0.4; %  minimum correlation to plot
line_to_remove = isnan(weights) | abs(weights)<threshold;
% remove the lines from the graph:
G = G.rmedge(find(line_to_remove)); %#ok<FNDSB>
% plot it:
p = plot(G); % for labeling the lines uncomment add: 'EdgeLabel',G.Edges.Weight
p.NodeColor = 'k';
% color positive in blue and negative in red:
p.EdgeColor = [G.Edges.Weight<0.' zeros(numel(G.Edges.Weight),1) G.Edges.Weight>0.'];
% set the thickness of the lines:
p.LineWidth = abs(G.Edges.Weight)*5;
axis off
```

If you want the nodes to be in a grid, then you need to set the `XData` and `YData` properties of the plotted graph.

```
% get the grid coordinates for all nodes
[x,y] = ndgrid(1:ceil(sqrt(n)),1:ceil(sqrt(n)));
x = x(:);
y = y(:);
% set the nodes in a 'grid' structure
p.XData = x(1:n);
p.YData = y(1:n);
axis ij % flip the plot so it will be orderd like in a matrix
```

with `n = 9` it will look like this (using some random `Corr_M`):

```
Corr_M =
            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
       0.9504            0            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
     0.016371      0.24554            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
     -0.11467     -0.19375     -0.30812            0            0            0            0            0            0
     -0.01241    -0.090871      0.74444      0.34121            0            0            0            0            0
     -0.21623      0.36844      0.83935     -0.83914     -0.12302            0            0            0            0
    -0.011428   -0.0077929     -0.26243     -0.98249     -0.57997      0.55024            0            0            0
      0.64245      -0.6027      0.51424      0.62646      0.32854      0.18052     0.055688            0            0
     -0.51699      0.47885      0.44677      0.18128      0.26819     -0.67849    -0.034057      0.28652            0
```

[image: corr_graph]

One of the problems with graph plots is the very small text that you can't change. If this important, read the [following suggestion](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/293683-changing-the-fontsize-of-matlab-diagraph-plot#answer_229113).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are a couple of things I don't understand: 1) If `n=5`, shouldn't the resulting graph have 25 nodes? 2) In the second to last line, what is the purpose of `5'`? Matlab just evaluates this as `5`. Did you mean write `(abs(weights)*5)'`?

Comment: The matrix `Corr_M` is the result of `corr(M)` where `M` is an `n`x`n` random matrix. It has `n^2` values (=25) but as you mentioned - it's symmetric, and the main diagonal is all `1`, so only the upper (or left) triangle is needed.

Comment: The strictly upper triangle of a `n x n` matrix has `n(n-1)/2` entries, not `n`.

Comment: @Lovsovs - right, and this is why there are 10 edged (lines) in the example. I never wrote that there should be only `n`. Anyway, this answer still holds, whether you use `corr` or any other function. All it does is visualize the numbers in the matrix.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood, forgive me. Thank you for this solution! Is there any way to change the layout of the nodes from a pentagon to a grid?

Comment: When trying to run your code, I get: 


`Error using matlab.internal.graph.constructFromEdgeList (line 146)
Weight must have as many elements as edge list or be a scalar.`

`Error in graph (line 264)
                matlab.internal.graph.constructFromEdgeList(...`

Comment: @Lovsovs, I have rewritten the answer and added more explanations. It should also solve the problem of zero correlation now.